# How to remove text highlight color with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm building a note editor in which everything is structured in terms of blocks so when the user selects multiple blocks i.e multiple paragraphs I'm showing a blue overlay over the box container of the block similar to notion.so, But what I want to do is when I show the blue overlay I want to remove the highlight color of the text (The blue highlight when you select text) I've tried user select none but it doesn't work as the class gets added afterwards, I've also tried `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` but it also doesn't seem to work

Demo:
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/4910570?key=905d37aa5750ac2ef7055097c33b6f2b

Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-vgel5?file=/Paragraph.js

```
import React from "react";

import { Popover } from "antd";
import GrabMenu from "../GrabMenu/GrabMenu";

import grabIcon from "../../icons/noteeditor/grab-icon.svg";
import { useSelected, useSlateStatic } from "slate-react";
import showSelectedHalo from "../../utils/showSelectedHalo";
import getClassNameForStyling from "../../utils/getClassNameForStyling";

const Paragraph = (props) => {
  const selected = useSelected();
  const editor = useSlateStatic();

  return (
    <div {...props.attributes} className="paragraph-block block">
      <div className="grab-icon-container" contentEditable={false}>
        <img
          src={grabIcon}
          className="grab-icon"
          onClick={props.clearSelection}
        />
      </div>
// The blue overlay
      <div
        className={
          showSelectedHalo(editor, selected, props.element) || props.allSelected
            ? "block-selected-halo block-selected"
            : "block-selected-halo"
        }
        contentEditable={false}
      ></div> 
// Text
      <p className={`${getClassNameForStyling(props).trim()}`}>
        {props.children}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Paragraph;
```

Comment: Here you go, I didn't add it because it's not really specific to my problem

Comment: This link may help you give a simple example set of code which we can base answers on - I don't think all that react stuff is going to be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example as you say it isn't specific to the problem.

Comment: @AHaworth https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-vgel5?file=/Paragraph.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide that blue color everywhere use this rule:

```
::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: if I use this it also hides the text

Comment: @Rohan - Isn't that what you're looking for? Could you please provide a photo for what you want to achieve?

Comment: I created a sandbox please check it out

Comment: Thanks it was another library which had color to white that's why it was not showing up but it worked, Thanks a lot!